# Calculated column based on subgroup condition

Tags: excel, excel-2013, dax, calculated-columns, powerquery

I need a solution based on DAX:

My Table:

```
Date       User       Code         Column1     
1/1/17     Karl       A            
1/1/17     Karl       B            
1/1/17     Joan       G            
1/1/17     Joan       B            
1/1/17     Maria      Z            
1/1/17     Maria      H            
1/1/17     Maria      F
```

How to create a loop or function in DAX, where I fill rows in `Column1` based on a few conditions:

For each date in `[Date]` and for each User in `[User]` if the value "A" or "Z" exists in column `[Code]`, then put "AUTO" in `[Column1]`, else if the value "A" or "Z" does not exist in `[Code]` then put "NOT AUTO" in `[Column1]` like below:

My Table:

```
Date       User       Code         Column1     
1/1/17     Karl       A            Auto
1/1/17     Karl       B            Auto
1/1/17     Joan       G            NOT Auto
1/1/17     Joan       B            Not Auto
1/1/17     Maria      Z            Auto
1/1/17     Maria      H            Auto
1/1/17     Maria      F            Auto
....       .....      .....        .....
```

Is possible in DAX to solve this?

Note: As per discussion below, I need the DAX to function in Excel 2013, so newer functions may not be available.

Comment: Why did your Codes change in the second table?

Comment: i correct this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (assuming your table is named `Users`):

```
Column1 = 
    VAR AllCodes = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Users[Code]), ALL(Users[Code]))
    RETURN IF("A" IN AllCodes || "Z" IN AllCodes, "Auto", "NOT Auto")
```

The variable `AllCodes` calculates the set of all codes associated with the user and date in each row. (Note that I use `CALCULATETABLE` since I want to return multiple values.)

Using this, we test if either `A` or `B` is in `AllCodes` and assign `Auto` or `NOT Auto` accordingly.

---

If you can't use variables, try substituting the variable definition into the equation:

```
Column1 = IF("A" IN CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Users[Code]), ALL(Users[Code])) ||
             "Z" IN CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Users[Code]), ALL(Users[Code])),
             "Auto", "NOT Auto")
```

---

If the `IN` syntax doesn't work in your old version of DAX, then try `CONTAINS` like I suggested:

```
Column1 = IF(CONTAINS(CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Users[Code]),ALL(Users[Code])), [Code], "A") ||
             CONTAINS(CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(Users[Code]),ALL(Users[Code])), [Code], "Z"),
             "Auto", "NOT Auto")
```

---

All three of these solutions reproduce your sample data in the latest version of Power BI desktop.

[image: Power BI]

---

**Edit:**

Upon reflection, it occurred to me that if there are additional columns, this may not work as expected since there will be additional row contexts to be considered. If there are additional columns, you probably want to use `ALLEXCEPT(Users, Users[Date], Users[User])` instead of `ALL(Users[Code])`. This will remove all row context except the ones explicitly specified (`Date` and `User`) instead of only removing the `Code` row context.

Comment: what with column [Date] ? this is every import, becuase my subgroup is User for each date

Comment: @SevaArve Right, this should group by `Date` and `User`.  If you don't want to group by `Date`, then add an `ALL(Users[Date])` argument to the `CALCULATETABLE` function.

Comment: @SevaArve Ugh. I guess you can just substitute that in then. It's not as clean.

Comment: how can i substitue this ?

Comment: @SevaArve Ugh. I think the `CONTAINS` function is older. That might work instead.

Comment: Calculation error in column 'Users'[]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Comment: how group this IF for each User and Date ??

Comment: @SevaArve I've tested and both solutions work in a modern DAX environment. The trick is rewriting it for Excel 2013 (which you didn't initially specify).

Comment: in modern dax you can groupby for each date and for user?

Comment: @SevaArve Yes. You can in older DAX as well, but you can't use the newer functions. You have to use old ones. Please try my latest edit.

Comment: In PowerBI Desktop yoru solution doesnt work. 
The change only rows, where value is "A" and "Z"

Comment: @SevaArve I don't know what to tell you. It works perfectly fine for me. See attached screenshot. If it doesn't work for you in Power BI, show me what you are seeing.

Comment: If have more different columns in dataset, then this formula still work ?

Comment: @SevaArve I would think so, but why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: @SevaArve Please see my edit regarding additional columns. In the future, please fully specify your question rather than leaving out important details like additional columns.